# Navigation page push multiple times when click on listview xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation

I am new at xamarin forms. There is a favorite page list inside my application. This list works like a shortcut but when i navigate from this list page push multiple times that i click on listview. When i click first time push that page 1 time then i back and then click on that page1 second time page push 2 times. I had to press back button 2 times. I hope I was able to explain my problem.

[image]

```
 private async void favPageList_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mpage = e.Item as FlyoutItemPage;
        if (mpage != null)
        {
            var yetkiList = await serviceManager.getKullaniciYetkiList(kullaniciKodu, myDBName);
            foreach (var item in yetkiList)
            {
                userAuthorities.Add(item);
            }
            if (mpage.Title == "Anasayfa" || mpage.Title == "Çıkış")
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(mpage.TargetPage)));
             
            }
            else
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < userAuthorities.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (mpage.Title == userAuthorities[i].BASLIK)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine($"fpage title: {mpage.Title} userAuth title: {userAuthorities[i].BASLIK}");
                        if (userAuthorities[i].VIEW == "E")
                        {

                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(mpage.TargetPage)));
                        
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(new AlertConfig
                            {
                                Message = "Giriş yetkiniz bulunmuyor!",
                                OkText = "Tamam"

                            });
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            


        }
        

    }
```

That is my code to navigation.

Comment: Either: 1) you are adding `favPageList_ItemTapped` to an event handler, but never removing it. So that the second time that is called twice. OR 2) userAuthorities is accumulating another entry each time, so your foreach loop runs twice. OR 3) maybe its because you keep doing `new NavigationPage(...)`. Why? You are already in a NavigationPage, right? Maybe  do `await Navigation.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(mpage.TargetPage));`

Comment: I removed for loop, then get page information from my service, and then delete HomePage. It was unnecessary. And problem solved. That for loop was a problem here.